# How can I train Tesseract on Windows

Tags: windows, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to train tesseract for work on windows. The process finish well but when I make the call to

```
tesseract.exe file.tiff out
```

after this the run, file is empty.

I don´t know what is happen here, I did the same process under linux and work perfectly.

I think that the problem could be the generation with the mftraining.exe.
It throw this messages:

```
Warning: no protos/configs for a in CreateIntTemplates()
Warning: no protos/configs for f in CreateIntTemplates()
Warning: no protos/configs for l in CreateIntTemplates()
Warning: no protos/configs for o in CreateIntTemplates() 
Warning: no protos/configs for r in CreateIntTemplates()
Error: no configs for class a in mftraining
Error: no configs for class f in mftraining
Error: no configs for class l in mftraining
Error: no configs for class o in mftraining
Error: no configs for class r in mftraining
```

any other end without problems

Somebody can help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but if you're looking for a way to train current version of Tesseract (4+) on Windows, I have created a GUI that automates all the process. It requires Python 3. [Here](https://github.com/buliasz/tesstrain-windows-gui) is my GitHub repository that contains all the sources and compiled portable executable file.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to follow this manuel from google on how to train tesseract ?

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Comment: Yes i follow that steps and it training well using linux but on the windows enviroment do not work appropriately. Thanks

Comment: The link has died sometime during the 4+ years that has passed since you write your answer. Do you have an updated link?

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=1458):

> 1. Training is not supported on windows.
> 2. If you want to test/fix something, use the current code from repository (it should be posible to build it with msys2 on windows)

Training tools are only included in `Tesseract 3.03+`. Separate commands are used to build the main program `tesseract.exe` and the training tools. Shown as below.

[image]

I have successfully built the main program on Windows 7 with MSYS2. But I failed to build the training tools.

### Update

Now I have turned to use Xubuntu to build both the main program and the training tools. And the training process can be carried out. Though there's a lot of details to be tuned.